# Drain pipe P trap leaking under sink

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, kitchen-sink

I removed the P trap and pipe from the old kitchen and tried to reuse it for the new kitchen remodeling:

[image]

However, it's leaking water at the connection from the white pipe to the metal P trap:

[image]

I even used a new washer. What I realized is that I can only push the white pipe into the P trap for like 1/2 in. But when I tighten the nut, the plastic pipe is stil quite loose. If I pull it out by hand, I still can separate it.

My questions are:

1. Is this installation done correctly? Anything missing?
2. Did I use the wrong washer or wrong pipe? This is just 1/2" right?
3. Maybe the whole thing is bad. Should I replace the entire P trap and pipe set for the new remodel?

I played around with the same setup at Home Depot and it's very tight when I tighten the nuts. I mean I could not just yank out the pipe easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your P trap is put together backward!** The bent piece (called the "outlet") is supposed to come off of the SHORT side of the trap. If you look, the side where your outlet is connected now in that picture has a long wider section at the top. THAT is where your tailpiece (the straight part coming down from the sink) is supposed to go, it's wider so that the tailpiece fits down in there before you then clamp around it with the tapered washer.

[image]

Comment: Yes I realized that but it is the old "configuration" of this sink in the house for at least 20 years and it never leaked (surprised).

Comment: Leaked in the past or not, it is nonetheless backward. Luck is not a strategy...